# what should I pass as end character to system commands such as grep?

Tags: c, bash, grep, exec, dup2

```
void pipe_execute(char all[][MAX_SIZE],int i,int n)
{
    if(i==n)
    {
        execute(all[i-1]);
    }
    else
    {
        int fd[2];
        char cmd1[100];
        pipe(fd);
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid==0)
        {
        dup2(fd[1],fileno(stdout));
        execute(all[i-1]);
        }
        else
        {
        wait(NULL);
        dup2(fd[0],fileno(stdin));
        pipe_execute(all,i+1,n);
        }
    }
}
void execute(char cmd[])
{
    char *a = strtok(cmd," ");
    char *b = strtok(NULL," ");
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid==0)
    execlp(a,a,b,(char*)NULL);
    else
    {
    wait(NULL);
    }   
}
```

In this program suppose
all[0] = "ls"
all[1] = "grep aa"
i=1
n=2

Execution of grep doesn't stop after "grep a", may be it is waiting for some special character, I've tried all like '\0','\n',EOF etc but it didn't work. What should I send to end grep?

Comment: You have to close all the stray file descriptors.  In general, you should be doing `pipe(fd);  if(fork()==0) {close(fd[0]); dup2(fd[1], 1); close(fd[1])...`  If any of the processes still has a write end of the pipe open, `grep` will continue to wait for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn’t stop because it is waiting for input. Close its `stdin` to have it quit. If it’s attached to a tty, send `Ctrl-D` to it. Another option is to kill it with an appropriate signal, but I don’t think you want that.

Comment: and for closing stdin, I have created a thread which runs this execute and main thread sleeps for some time and closes the stdin.  Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Well, usually the same process/thread which sends data to a pipe closes the stream when there are no more data to send. If this approach doesn’t work for you, implementing a timeout, as you have done, is your only remaining option.